# Python Django model signals Post_Save query object does not contain saved object

Tags: python, django, django-models, signals

My intention is to send a notification once the properties field is updated. I also need to include details of the property updated in the notification sent.

The signal is triggered and the notification is sent but I can't get the property being updated from the host instance.

I instead end up getting what was saved the last time the signal was triggered.

Anybody who knows how I can get the property instance being updated when the signal is being triggered?

Please help.

`property = host.properties.last() #` This refuses to query the host. property instance that has just been updated. Instead, it picks the one that was updated the last time the signal was triggered.

Is my query the problem or does post_save get triggered before the property field is updated?

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
from django_model_changes import ChangesMixin
from django.conf import settings
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from ..services.notification import NotificationService



class Host(ChangesMixin, models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='host', unique=True)
    properties = models.ManyToManyField('Property', related_name='hosts', blank=True)
    one_field = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    another_field = models.OneToOneField('Location')


    def to_dict(self):

        if self.phone == None:
            number = None
        else:
            number = self.phone.national_number 

    return {
        'one_field': self.one_field,
        'another_field': self.properties.count() - self.limit,
    }

    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'Host {} {} {} <{}>'.format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name, self.phone, self.user.email)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'host'
        verbose_name = 'Host'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Hosts'

@receiver(post_save, sender=Host)
def send_email_if_change_detected_in_properties(sender, instance, **kwargs):
if instance.properties:
    host = instance
    property = host.properties.last() # This refuses to take the host.property instance that has just been updated. Instead it picks the one that was updated last previously.
    NotificationService.send_new_property_assigned_to_host(host)
    print "Done"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work since `properties` is `ManyToMany` field. Django fires `post_save` before updating m2m fields. M2m fields are updated after that and then another signal - `m2m_changed` is fired. So, to track changes in `properties`, you need to use this signal 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed

Comment: thanks,for that info, let me try it out and get back to you

Comment: That helped, are you sure how I can avoid the m2M_changed signal being called twice?